# flutter code suggestions aren't working after v1.0.0 update

Tags: flutter, dart

i didn't write any flutter code for a long time, when i came back i had a really annoying problem and it is slowing me down.

the code completion/suggestions (when hitting ctrl+space) is working fine, except when i want to see suggestions for a property of a widget.

i can't remember the specific update that messes this up, but when i go to download an older version of flutter, it seems the last working update is v1.0.0, after that the problem appears.

i've tried different PCs and IDEs, they all have the same problem.

screenshot of it working when pressing ctrl+space on:

```
Container(
    alignment: // <<< Pressing Ctrl+Space here
)
```

[image]

another screenshot after the v1.0.0 update:

[image]

---

**UPDATE: after trying for 6 hours, i figured out a workaround and knew the cause of the problem.**

you have to download the latest version of Flutter SDK.
and the dart SDK version 2.1.1 from (https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive)

and only take two files:

First file: `dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe` and copy it to `Flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin`

Second file: `dart-sdk\bin\snapshots\analysis_server.dart.snapshot` and copy it to `Flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\snapshots`

it's not a great solution but at least it works for now, you will lose all the features that were introduced after the 2.1.1 update.

Comment: If you scroll the property isn't there at all or is it down?

Comment: Not sure if this is it but android studio or flutter or dart add support lately for smart autocomplete that learns what you use and change the ordering and suggestions based on what it learned about your usage.  But if you don't get the property at all even if you scroll it is not the problem so try invalidate Caches/Restart.

Comment: @guy it does show up, but it's annoying to scroll down and search for it, especially if i don't know what properties are available to use.